# Melt multiple columns into datetime index

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for advice as to tidy my DataFrame.

Currently i have an index of datetime format with years days and months, but my column headers are hours (see the code below). The values in the hourly columns are energy usage numbers.

```
import pandas as pd

# creating dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2015/01/01', '2015/01/02','2015/01/03'],
               'ID': [2, 3,4],
                'REGION4': ['LM', 'LM','LM'],
                'SITECODE': ['RESIDENTIAL', 'RESIDENTIAL','RESIDENTIAL'],
                'HOUR_1': [10, 20,30],
                'HOUR_2': [21,25,20],
                'HOUR_3':[40,50,60],'HOUR_4':[40,50,60],'HOUR_5':[40,50,60],'HOUR_6':[40,50,60],'HOUR_7':[40,50,60],
                'HOUR_8':[40,50,60],'HOUR_9':[40,50,60],'HOUR_10':[40,50,60],'HOUR_11':[40,50,60],'HOUR_12':[40,50,60],
                'HOUR_13':[40,50,60],'HOUR_14':[40,50,60],'HOUR_15':[40,50,60],'HOUR_16':[40,50,60],'HOUR_17':[40,50,60],
                'HOUR_18':[40,50,60],'HOUR_19':[40,50,60],'HOUR_20':[40,50,60],'HOUR_21':[40,50,60],'HOUR_22':[40,50,60],
                'HOUR_23':[40,50,60],'HOUR_24':[40,50,60]})

# setting date column to be index of datetime type
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df2.set_index(df2['Date'],drop = True,inplace = True)
del df2['Date']

# trying to melt the hour columns into the datetime format so that we simply have the datetime and then the values
df2_melted = pd.melt(frame=df2, id_vars = ['Index','ID','REGION4','SITECODE'], value_vars = ['HOUR_1','HOUR_2','HOUR_3','HOUR_4','HOUR_5','HOUR_6','HOUR_7','HOUR_8','HOUR_9','HOUR_10','HOUR_11','HOUR_12','HOUR_13','HOUR_14','HOUR_15','HOUR_16','HOUR_17','HOUR_18','HOUR_19','HOUR_20','HOUR_21','HOUR_22','HOUR_23','HOUR_24'])
```

I want to know how to convert my columns into the existing datetime index, resulting in an index of datetimes with hourly values included, and resulting in one column labelled "energy usage" or something along those lines.

I am thinking of melting the dataframe, but i cant seem to wrap my head around melting the columns into the existing datetime index as hours. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Post code as code. Make a minimal example as text, post it here, and show what you tried. We can't copy and paste an image into our consoles to experiment.

Comment: So here is my code to melt the columns into one column;                
 northern_melted = pd.melt(frame=northern, id_vars = ['Index','ID','REGION4','SITECODE'], value_vars = ['HOUR_1','HOUR_2','HOUR_3','HOUR_4','HOUR_5','HOUR_6','HOUR_7','HOUR_8','HOUR_9','HOUR_10','HOUR_11','HOUR_12','HOUR_13','HOUR_14','HOUR_15','HOUR_16','HOUR_17','HOUR_18','HOUR_19','HOUR_20','HOUR_21','HOUR_22','HOUR_23','HOUR_24'])........ the problem with this is the original datetime index has been changed into an integer index, and i still need to convert these hour values into the datetime index..

Comment: @JasonOrr Put that code in your question.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's impossible to read, and all relevant information should be included in the question. Use the edit button under the question to put all the information into the question. And please get rid of the image in favor of a piece of code to generate a minimal sample DF.

Comment: Thank you guys for those tips! i think i have provided a better question now with some code to play with. Please let me know if you have any insights.